# Explanation of time dilation using special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Special relativity is based on inertial frames(i.e, frames travelling with a constant velocity). Time dilation is a consequence of this theory, which is based on inertial frames. Then how can we explain time dilation of circular particle beams, which is in a non-inertial frame? Also, how can we use theory of special relativity while justifying twin paradox, assuming that the travelling twin switches to two inertial frames,one towards earth and other away from earth? Is there any acceleration when the switch takes place? If so, how does special relativity explain it?

Comment: Soecial relativity has no problem with acceleration: SR is a theory of *flat spacetime*, not one restricted to particular sorts of observers.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: From 1996:  [Acceleration in Special Relativity](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/acceleration.html) - *"It's a common misconception that special relativity cannot handle accelerating objects or accelerating reference frames."*

Answer (score 0):

Circular motion is a bit of a special case. The acceleration necessary is anti-radial. If this is the only acceleration speed is constant.

In special relativity the effect of time dilation is due to the magnitude of relative velocity (i.e. the relative speed), we can treat the particular case of circular motion the same as a constant velocity scenario.

For a body that is changing speed, the total time difference will be the integral of all the infinitesimal $\delta t$ time dilation effects

$t_{rel}= t_0 + \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v(t)^2}{c^2}}} dt $

Where $v(t)$ describes how speed (or velocity) varies over time.

In reality a body cannot reverse direction without undergoing acceleration, but since this is just a bit more complicated to deal with, and doesn't demonstrate anything more paradoxical, it is usually neglected when the twin paradox is presented.